# SQL Finding multiple combinations in 2 tables (with all records)

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I have two tables, one with some user configurations (#USERCONFIG) and the other (#COMBINATIONS), multiples combinations of configurations I need to find in the first table.

```
CREATE TABLE #COMBINATIONS (INDEX1 INT, MENU CHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE #USERCONFIG (USERID VARCHAR(10), MENU VARCHAR(10))


INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS VALUES (1, 'ABC300')
INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS VALUES (1, 'ABC400')
INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS VALUES (2, 'ABC100')
INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS VALUES (2, 'ABC500')
INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS VALUES (2, 'ABC600')


INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHJ', 'ABC100')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHJ', 'ABC500')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHJ', 'ABC600')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHC', 'ABC100')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHC', 'ABC500')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHA', 'ABC100')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHA', 'ABC200')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHA', 'ABC300')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHA', 'ABC400')
INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG VALUES ('SMITHA', 'ABC600')
```

With this example data, I want the resultset to look like this:

```
'SMITHJ', '2'
'SMITHA', '1'
'SMITHC', '2'
```

Where it will return all users that have a match of configurations from the combinations table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is `smithc` there? It is missing ABC600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will list users and the *complete* combinations they have. If it helps, you can think of it as the recipe-ingredient and user-ingredient textbook problem:

```
SELECT alluser.USERID, index_menu.INDEX1
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM #USERCONFIG) AS alluser
CROSS JOIN #COMBINATIONS AS index_menu
LEFT JOIN #USERCONFIG AS user_menu ON alluser.USERID = user_menu.USERID AND index_menu.MENU = user_menu.MENU
GROUP BY alluser.USERID, index_menu.INDEX1
HAVING COUNT(index_menu.MENU) = COUNT(user_menu.MENU)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will get that result:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#COMBINATIONS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #COMBINATIONS;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#USERCONFIG') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #USERCONFIG;

CREATE TABLE #COMBINATIONS (INDEX1 INT, MENU VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE #USERCONFIG (USERID VARCHAR(10), MENU VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #COMBINATIONS (INDEX1, MENU) VALUES 
(1, 'ABC301'),
(1, 'ABC401'),
(2, 'ABC102'),
(2, 'ABC502'),
(2, 'ABC602');

INSERT INTO #USERCONFIG (USERID, MENU) VALUES 
('SMITHJ', 'ABC102'),
('SMITHJ', 'ABC502'),
('SMITHJ', 'ABC602'),
('SMITHC', 'ABC102'),
('SMITHC', 'ABC502'),
('SMITHA', 'ABC102'),
('SMITHA', 'ABC200'),
('SMITHA', 'ABC301'),
('SMITHA', 'ABC401'),
('SMITHA', 'ABC602');

SELECT USERID, INDEX1
FROM
(
    SELECT uconf.USERID, comb.INDEX1, 
     COUNT(*) AS Total,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY uconf.USERID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, comb.INDEX1 ASC) AS Rnk
    FROM #USERCONFIG uconf
    INNER JOIN #COMBINATIONS comb
      ON comb.MENU = uconf.MENU
    GROUP BY uconf.USERID, INDEX1
) q
WHERE Rnk = 1
ORDER BY Total DESC, USERID;
```

**Returns:**

```
USERID  INDEX1
SMITHJ  2
SMITHA  1
SMITHC  2
```